# How to get text on same line as my CSS number and circle?

Tags: html, css

This is a two part question:

First question is I've created a circle with a number inside of it in CSS. How do I fill the circle with a color?

Second question is how do I get the words "Opportunity #1" on the same line as the "circle with the number inside of it"

So I would like it to be like this:

1 Opportunity #1
We are always interested in meeting like-minded, creative individuals to join our team. Please introduce yourself by submitting your cover letter, resume and portfolio to the email below.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/0236oyce/19/

Here's my code:

```
<div class="circle"><span class="number">1</span></div>
<h3>Opportunity #1</h3>
<p>We are always interested in meeting like-minded, creative individuals to join our team. Please introduce yourself by submitting your cover letter, resume and portfolio to the email below.</p>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.circle {
border: 0.1em solid grey;
border-radius: 100%;
height: 2em;
width: 2em;
text-align: center;
```

}

```
.circle .number {
    margin-top: 0.10em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #F66511;
}

h3 {
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#232323;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    text-align:left;
    font-weight:bold;
}

p {
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#616161;
    margin:0 0 0 50px;
    text-align:left;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

Comment: `background-color: red;` on `.circle` to color it

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

**Using Floats:**

```
.circle {
    border: 0.1em solid grey;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    background:#fc0;
    float:left;
    margin:0 20px;
}

.circle .number {
    margin-top: 0.10em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #F66511;
}

h3 {
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#232323;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    text-align:left;
    font-weight:bold;
}

p {
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#616161;
    margin:0 0 0 50px;
    text-align:left;
    font-weight:normal;
    clear:both;
}
```

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4z5xro89/)

**Option 2**

**Using Blocks**

```
.header {
    display:block;
}
.circle {
    border: 0.1em solid grey;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    background:#fc0;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:0 20px;
}
.circle .number {
    margin-top: 0.10em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #F66511;
}
h3 {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#232323;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:left;
    font-weight:bold;
}
p {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#616161;
    margin:0 0 0 50px;
    text-align:left;
    font-weight:normal;
    clear:both;
}
```

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fxmnghcc/)